# How do I get the unique elements and count from an array of hashes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array of hashes, and I want the unique values and count out of it.
I have:

```
a = [{:key => 2}, {:key => 1}, {:key => 4}, {:key => 1}]
```

I want see:

```
a = [{:key => 2}, {:key => 1, :count =>2}, {:key => 4}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = [{:key => 2}, {:key => 1}, {:key => 4}, {:key => 1}]
b = a.clone
a.uniq!
a.inject([]) { |result,h| h[:count]=b.count(h) if b.count(h) > 1 ; result << h; result }

 => [{:key=>2}, {:key=>1, :count=>2}, {:key=>4}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You will just have to iterate over the array and count how many times each key occurs, and then sum it all together by building a new array with the result.

The below code snippet should do it.

```
a = [{:key => 2}, {:key => 1}, {:key => 4}, {:key => 1}]

counts = Hash.new(0)

a.map do |item|
  counts[item[:key]] += 1
end

a = counts.collect do |key, count|
  if count > 1
    {:key => key, :count => count}
  else
    {:key => key}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a.each {|h| count = a.count(h); if count > 1; dup_h = h.clone; h.merge!({:count => count}); a.delete(dup_h); end }
```

Answer (score -1):

The most concise way there is (I think) is this:

```
a.uniq.map{|hsh| c = a.count(hsh); c == 1 || hsh[:count] = c; hsh}
```

or if you don't want to modify the hashes in a:

```
a.uniq.map{|hsh| h = hsh.dup; c = a.count(hsh); c == 1 || h[:count] = c; h}
```

A (marginally) prettier solution that yields a different result is:

```
a.uniq.group_by{|hsh| a.count(hsh)}
#=> {1=>[{:key=>2}, {:key=>4}], 2=>[{:key=>1}]}
```

Check out the documentation on [Enumerable#count](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/count) and [Enumerable#group_by](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by) to learn more of what you can do with those.
Ruby's core is actually quite powerful.